# Local npm start error while setting up Spartacus 5.2

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am trying to setup Spartacus 5.2(Followed steps: https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_COMMERCE_COMPOSABLE_STOREFRONT/cfcf687ce2544bba9799aa6c8314ecd0/5de67850bd8d487181fef9c9ba59a31d.html#loio5de67850bd8d487181fef9c9ba59a31d)

During initial schematic setup received below warning.
[image]

while running npm start received couple of build errors.

Can I please know is there any step missed during setup?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This mainly happens when you have an incorrect angular version installed. For 5.2 you need to use 14.2.0

Use nvm to switch between different version